# i want to click on a element of a drop down

Tags: selenium, webdriver, invisible

i want to click on a element of a drop down which comes up after clicking on hidden element and hidden element display after mouse hovering. i am using selenium web driver, please help me how it is possible.

I tried using action class and JSExecutor but couldn't got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Select** here.

For example:

> driver.get("http://example.com");
>   Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("value")));
>   select.selectByIndex(1);

Change the index value depending upon the drop-down list/option position.

Comment: first i have to search the hidden element , then i have to click on it, clicking on hidden element generates a drop down on that i have to click..can u tell me the complete code...select class will only select the code from drop down.

Comment: Can I have more details on the app? url or similar page will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Text");
```

If you want to get more helpful information, please provide some html code or 
how you have tried to click on a element of a drop down :)

Regards, Sergii

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Mousehovers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.sample.com");

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
    WebElementmenuHoverLink=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'xx')]"));
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement>menuHoverLink1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xxxxxxx"));
    System.out.println(menuHoverLink1.size());

    for(int i=0;i<menuHoverLink1.size();i++){
         System.out.println(menuHoverLink1.get(i).getText());

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If u r satisfied with the above code,pls select the upper arrow "This answer is useful"

Comment: I agree with u Thread.sleep(5000) is more,but without Thread.sleep() is it printing the text in console? I don't think . I am trying to get the text without Thread.sleep() , but i didn't get the text. If u want the text definitely put Thread.sleep(1000) at least.If u get the text with out Thread.sleep() please let me know i will try to do that.

Comment: If u r satisfied with the above code,pls select the upper arrow "This answer is useful"